# Is there a notion for functions $p$ fulfilling $p(x,y) = \int p(x,z)p(z,y) dz$

Tags: functional-analysis, probability-theory, probability-distributions, relations

is there a name for the class of measurable functions $p:X\times X\to [0,1]$ (where $X$ denotes a measurable space) that satisfy the following two properties?

1. $p(x,x)=1\;$ for all $x\in X$,
2. $p(x,y) = \int_X p(x,z)p(z,y) dz\;$ for all $x,y \in X$,
3. $1= \int_X p(x,z) dz\;$ for all $x\in X$.

Comment: Why use $k$ in the title and $p$ in the body?

Comment: In my notes I used k, but decided that p would make more sense. :/

Comment: Looks like absolutely continuous Markovian kernels if $\int p(z,y)\,dz=1$.

Comment: @GasparLeMarc One key to asking a good question is to not confuse your reader. I edited the title for you.

Comment: @ThomasAndrews Thank you very much :) This was my first post here. I will be more careful in the future.

Comment: @OliverDiaz in fact I missed this requirement. Thank you! I will add this in the post.

Comment: The $p(x,y) = \int_X p(x,z)p(z,y) dz$ property makes $P:L^1(X)\to L^1(X),\ Pf(x)=\int_X p(x,y)\,f(y)\,dy$ satisfy $P^2=P,$ i.e. it's a projection operator.